# Is the language of TMs that accept finite languages in $\mathbf{0}'$?

Tags: formal-languages, computability, turing-machines, undecidability

In [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/49000/2242) question it is asked, "Is the language of TMs that accept finite languages Turing-recognizable?".
It turns out this language $L=\{ \langle M \rangle \mid |L(M)| < \infty \}$ is not.
I ask this: We know that the halting problem is Turing-reducible to $L$ but is $L$ Turing-reducible to the halting problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your language $L$ is usually known as Fin or FIN, and is $\Sigma_2$-complete; see for example lecture notes of [Cohen Wallace](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~bwallace/ArithmeticalHierarchy.pdf). Since the halting problem is in $\Sigma_1$, it follows that $L$ cannot be reduced to the halting problem.